# Windows 10 and Ubuntu Studio dual boot configuration

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have 3x identical HP 6300 Pro SSFs with 2x 240GB SSDs and 16BG RAM in each. All three had Windows 10 installed, but later I added the 2nd SSD with the intent to install Ubuntu Studio.

My original intent wasn't to make them dual boot. I was going to do a "BIOS Boot", i.e. I'd just hit the 'Boot Menu' key and pick a drive.

On one, os-probe found the Windows volume and set up the GRUB menu. On the 2nd and 3rd, I was getting error messages from sdb. I learned that my US thumb drive had to be setup with a UEFI boot. I used Rufus and the 2nd box now starts with a GRUB menu.

The 3rd box, having the same error as the 2nd, seemed remedied at first by using same thumb drive. At first boot I got a GRUB menu and selected my Windows OS and it booted as usual. On a restart though, the GRUB menu was gone and the box now only boots into the Windows Boot Manager.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I only added the other examples to exemplify my shortsightedness. Normally when fiddling about, I'd make some notes, mental or written, on how I went about things but...
It boots to a blinking cursor so maybe I should reinstall? I've seen suggestions to disconnect / disable the Windows volume when installing, is that the way you suggest I go?

Comment: Nmath, thanks for your assistance. I followed your advice and it worked out. I got to partitioning, I chose Erase disk and when I saw the graphic at the bottom, I saw what I did wrong the 1st coupla times on this box. Previous, I'd installed it to a blank ext partition without efi space. This time I saw the efi partition and it breezed perfectly through the install and several boots to the US installation and Windows.